# Twitter Bootstrap Accordion - How to print with all expanded?

Tags: printing, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter Bootstrap accordions here and there throughout my site.  They work great and all that, the issue I just noticed is if I want to Print a page with one on it.  Ideally they should all expand if the page is to be printed for my purposes.

Does anyone know the best way to go about this?  I know I could hookup something via javascript to a Print button on the page, but let's assume that the user will use the browser's Print button - so tying javascript to this may not be an option.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12302819/422353) shows the right way to handle printing.

Answer (score 16):

i am using bootstrap 3.1.1 and the bootstrap.css as it comes by default.
i am also using the example accordion html from this page:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

and for me adding this rule to the
@media print {..} section of the .css file did the trick:

```
.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Works for Bootstrap 4 as well.

Answer (score 3):

In Bootstrap 4, you can use the [display utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#display-in-print), eg:

`<div class="collapse d-print-block">...</div>`

Comment: Also available in Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) and just style all of accordions as expanded, if the media is for printing.

Small example here, expands all accordions only for printing:

```css
@media print {
    /* your stylesheet for printing, eg.: */
    .accordion-group .accordion-body.collapse {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: To make this work I had to add an !IMPORTANT to the height:auto.