# Printing with bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, printing-web-page

I have a page with bootstrap css layout. I am trying to print off a table. However the table looks nothing like it does on screen. I include the css file like this:

```
<link href='../bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Is there a way to get the printed table to look the same as on screen or do I have to create a specific css file just for the table I want to print?

Comment: See the accepted answer on this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302819/how-to-create-a-printable-twitter-bootstrap-page

Comment: Hi I looked at this answer and I seem to include the bootstrap css file like mentioned in that answer. If i change the the link tag to add media="print" it will not work for the on screen content.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 7):

You can apply the style sheet too both print and screen using `media='screen,print'`

```
 <link ../bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen,print'>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However this solution will remove the table borders. Perhaps I need to add a separate css file for @media=print which includes borders in tables?

Answer (score 5):

Replace every `col-md-` with `col-xs-`
eg: replace every `col-md-6` to `col-xs-6`.

And don't forget to use bootstrap table class.

This is the thing that worked for me to get me rid of this problem you can figure out what you have to replace.

## Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **media="all"** to assure your css will applied in all cases including printing. Using **media='screen,print'** did not work for me.

```
<link ../bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='all'>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For me all those methods don't work. Use this code:

```
@media print {
    .bg-primary th {
        background-color: transparent !important;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #095075 inset !important;
    }
}
```