# Grails bootstrap hidden-print not working as expected

Tags: css, grails, twitter-bootstrap-3, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

So, In our grails project we are using the `twitter-bootstrap:3.1.1` plugin.  Have not seen any major problems until now.

In our `layouts/main.gsp` we have added a nice nav bar to be there everywhere.  The only problem is we don't want it to print when our pages are printed.  In `2.3.2` in more than one case we would just add the class to hide the element.  As you can see below the `hidden-print` is added to the outside element.  When printed the page still includes the items marked to be hidden.

As a test, I decided I would put it on other random elements within the application and in all points it seems to ignore the no print request.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default hidden-print" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <g:link class="navbar-brand" uri="/">Eight States</g:link>
  </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><g:link controller="agency" action="index">Agency</g:link></li>
        <li><g:link controller="attendee" action="index">Attendee</g:link></li>
        <li><g:link controller="vendor" action="index">Vendor</g:link></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Reports <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><g:link controller="activityRegistration">Event Report</g:link></li>
            <li><g:link controller="attendee" action="flightReport">Flight Report</g:link></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
        <sec:ifLoggedIn><a href="${createLink(uri: '/j_spring_security_logout')}">Logout</a></sec:ifLoggedIn>
        <sec:ifNotLoggedIn><g:link controller='login' action='auth'>Login</g:link></sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: As a note... I initially had the outer set up as a `nav` as shown on the the bootstrap help but it did not seem to help.

Comment: Is it possible that the bootstrap css isn't being included for the print media type? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302819/how-to-create-a-printable-twitter-bootstrap-page

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Interesting find `<link href="/SomeProject/static/bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />` is how its being included in the project.

Comment: But should `@media print {
  .hidden-print {
    display: none !important;
  }
}` tell it to print properly?  Thats how its included in the document...  No css expert but I dont think there should be a print on that?

Comment: `<link href="/SomeProject/static/bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />` with the class `hidden-print` on navbar should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the CSS isn't being included when the media type is print.

```
<link href="/SomeProject/static/bundle-bundle_bootstrap_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection">
```

That only includes the CSS for screen and projection.

Regarding your comment: I'm very sure that if the media attribute on the link element doesn't include `print` then the CSS won't be parsed when printing.

Thus the media query within the CSS never gets a chance to run at all. If you look at the [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com) site you will see it doesn't include a media specification on the style sheet and thus is processed for all media types (including print).

Comment: I guess I will try to figure out a way to do a bug report on the plugin...   Turns out that it DOES need to have the `print` added.  You are a life saver and thanks for what you do :-)

Comment: No worries. Very glad to help when I can.

Comment: I love that guy. I was dealing with the exact same issue .. and not even after reading your full answer, i got it. (the media scope)   ;)