# Print Bootstrap button properly

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little issue while printing bootstrap buttons and the solutions I found aren't working. 
This solution didn't worked for me : [stackoverflow-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302819/how-to-create-a-printable-twitter-bootstrap-page)

I've also tryed to change my browser print settings to force printing background colors without success in Firefox and Chrome.

My button looks like this : [image] and if I print it it shows like this : [image]

My PHP code for that button is : `echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\">$value</button>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Bootstrap CSS contains this CSS which sets a bunch of styles for printing:

```
@media print {
    *, :after, :before {
      color: #000!important;
      text-shadow: none!important;
      background: 0 0!important;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
      box-shadow: none!important;
    }
}
```

You can solve your issue by either:

1. Fix your CSS by removing some or all of the above lines (though you only *need* to remove the `background` and `colour` items.)
2. On the Bootstrap website, generate your own custom CSS with their [online generator](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) and untick the option `http://getbootstrap.com/customize/`.

Comment: It's working perfectly ! I've just removed the few lines. Thank you very much for your time !

Comment: Read this long winded explanation as to why this may not work: [#33410724](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410724/bootstrap-print-css-removes-background-color/36742058#36742058)