# Remove CSS @media print rules without modifying CSS files

Tags: javascript, html, css

I add bootstrap CSS files to my page. I don't want to modify the CSS files.

When I try yo print page, bootstrap modify media to print styles and remove all color properties.

How can I cancel bootstrap media settings for print?

This jquery code can remove all css; $("*").css("all","unset");

Is there way to remove css settings for only @media display{ .. }

Comment: By removing the print CSS rules from your stylesheet...

Comment: Nice :) but I don't want to change css files.

Comment: Okay, I don't know how you expect CSS rules to not apply without modifying the CSS.

Comment: use !important in css

Comment: Please **don't** use `!important` irresponsibly... And how would he do that if he doesn't want to modify the CSS files...?

Comment: I want a solve like   $("*").css("all","unset");

Comment: sorry you question is legitimate

Comment: unfortunately this code remove all css settings. I need to remove only which has media:print

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a printable Twitter-Bootstrap page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302819/how-to-create-a-printable-twitter-bootstrap-page)

Comment: You say you want to "solve like $("*").css("all","unset");", so... why don't you? Just put this in the onbeforeprint handler.

Comment: This code remove all css even @media screen{..} too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could get the stylesheet and remove each rule that starts with `'@media print'`, note that `styleSheets[0]` should be pointed to the stylesheet with the relevant rules.

```
for(var i=document.styleSheets[0].rules.length -1; i >0; i--){
   if(document.styleSheets[0].rules[i].cssText.indexOf("@media print") !=-1 )
   {
      document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(i);
   }
}
```

disclaimer: it's smelly code, I would not use this in an actual application. I would look for an appropriate solution (i.e. removing the lines from the css file)
However, sometimes you don't have control over all the files being served, or you just need to print a page without additional formatting. Then this would suffice.

Comment: What a pretty solution :) How couldn't I think that! I like that idea; to open a new window without style sheet files! Thank you :)

Comment: This has worked for me, thanks.