# Improve datatable printing

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a page where I need to print a chart (svg element) and an html table. Everything is fine here...The small issue what i have here is that the table
is not using the total width available in the page to print and also is not taking the style of table.
Here is my code:

```
  public print() {
        var popUpAndPrint = function () {
            var container = $('#container');
            var keyNumbers = $('#HtmlTableDIV');
            var mySVG: any = $("#container div svg");
            keyNumbers.appendTo(container);
            var width: any = mySVG.width();
            var height = mySVG.height();
            var printWindow = window.open('', 'PrintMap',
                'width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
            printWindow.document.writeln(container.html());
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
            printWindow.close();
        };
        setTimeout(popUpAndPrint, 500);
    }
```

and the result it is:[image: in the browser]

[image]

Comment: Your table is generated by highcharts or HTML ?

Comment: I am looking into this question and see if it working:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302819/how-to-create-a-printable-twitter-bootstrap-page

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo