# Change position of the page content on print

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, printing

I have some web page displayed in web browser:

[image]

When the same page is on the print mode I need to display the content of the page bottom 500 px:

[image]

Is there any way to implement it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a printable Twitter-Bootstrap page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302819/how-to-create-a-printable-twitter-bootstrap-page)

Comment: If the suggested link solve your issue I can close it as such?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is probably to create a separate stylesheet, something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="printable.css">
```

In this file you can add all styles that will only be picked up by the print mode of the browser